# Connecting From PolyBase To Hadoop

Tags: sql, hadoop, sql-server-2016

If we encounter the following exception in the following code, what does it mean?
I found no helpful definitions.

The exception is

> External Data Source information could not be retrieved due to an
>   internal error Exception of type 'JNI.JavaExceptionCheckException' was
>   thrown.: Error [Call From MIS-PC12/192.168.4.132 to 192.168.4.116:8020
>   failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: no further information; For more details see:
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused] occurred while
>   accessing external file.

And the code is

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyHadoopCluster2 WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION ='hdfs://192.168.4.116:8020',
    RESOURCE_MANAGER_LOCATION = '192.168.4.116:8020'
);
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFileFormat2 WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR ='|'));

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[CarSensor_Data] (
    [SensorKey] int NOT NULL,
    [CustomerKey] int NOT NULL,
    [GeographyKey] int NULL,
    [Speed] float NOT NULL,
    [YearMeasured] int NOT NULL
)
WITH (LOCATION='/D:\/',
DATA_SOURCE = MyHadoopCluster2,
FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat2

);
```

I don't know the location of the hadoop database, is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The LOCATION parameter needs to point to your **name-node** of your Hadoop cluster.

Comment: ihave found the solution 
you don't need to add RESOURCE_MANAGER_LOCATION to Exeternal Data Source that should point to name node ip 
and in Create External Table the location should be hdfs file
and the more important thing that in order to connect to cluster you have to copy the files coresite.xml ,hdfs-site.xml,mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml
from your name node conf file 
to the path of sql server 2016 instance 
C:\SqlServer2016\MSSQL13.SQLSERVER2016\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\Hadoop\conf

that was the solution in my case

Answer (score 0):

you will find the location in the:
\etc\hadoop\core-site.xml

in my case is: hdfs://localhost:9000

I found my resource manager location in the configuration under the yarn site --> Tools (http://localhost:8088/conf):

```
<property>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>

<value>localhost:8032</value>

<source>programatically</source>

</property>
```

The resource manager is an optional property. Try first to create the data source without it.

Kind regards, 
Paul